# Serving image file with Buffers - corrupted image

Tags: node.js, buffer

I'm trying to get into Node.js, I'm following some tutorials and I'm now stuck on an example that explains how to create a simple web server to serve static files, using `Buffers`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function serveStaticFile(file, res){
    var rs = fs.createReadStream(file);
    var ct = contentTypeForFile(file);
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : ct });

    rs.on('readable', function(){
        var d = rs.read();
        if (d) {
            if ( typeof d == 'string' ) 
                res.write(d);
            else if ( typeof d == 'object' && d instanceof Buffer )
                res.write(d.toString('utf8'));
        }
    });
    rs.on('error', function(e){
        res.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type" : "application/json" });
        var out = { error : "not_found", message : "'" + file + "' not found" };
        res.end(JSON.stringify(out) + "\n");
    });
    rs.on('end', function(){
        res.end();
    });
}
```

the function `serveStaticFile` runs on incoming requests, `file` is the filename of the file you want to retrieve.

This is `contentTypeForFile()`:

```
function contentTypeForFile(file){
    var ext = path.extname(file);
    switch(ext){
    case '.html': return "text/html";
    case '.js' : return "text/javascript";
    case '.css' : return "text/css";
    case '.jpg' :
    case '.jpeg' : return "image/jpeg";
    default : return "text/plain";
    }
}
```

Running this command `curl -o test.jpg http://localhost:8000/photo.jpg` in the cmd actually downloads and creates a *test.jpg* file in my folder, the problem is that when I try to open the image the image itself seems to be corrupted.

What am I doing wrong? How can I convert the `d.toString('utf8')` back to an actual image once it is downloaded?

---

**EDIT:** I think the problem is that the response headers are saved toghether with the file content itself.. if I open the image file with a text editor, this is the content:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Sat, 30 Aug 2014 00:31:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ [ ... ]
```

How can I get rid of the headers while saving the file?

Thanks in advance, regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `.toString('utf8')`, you don't want or need it there.  As a matter of fact, you can probably change this:

```
if (d) {
    if ( typeof d == 'string' ) 
        res.write(d);
    else if ( typeof d == 'object' && d instanceof Buffer )
        res.write(d.toString('utf8'));
}
```

To simply:

```
if (d) {
    res.write(d);
}
```

`res.write` already handles checking the type of data you're passing to it and encoding it properly. The only time you need to worry about it is if you send it a string that is not `utf8` encoded. From the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding):

> This sends a chunk of the response body. This method may be called
>   multiple times to provide successive parts of the body.
>   `chunk` can be a string or a buffer. If `chunk` is a string, the second
>   parameter specifies how to encode it into a byte stream. By default
>   the `encoding` is `utf8`.

---

I just re-read second part of your question and realized that you said that you found headers in the `test.jpg` file when you opened it with a text editor. The only way I know of that that can happen when using `curl` is by specifying the `-i` option. Something like: `curl -i -o test.jpg http://localhost:8000/photo.jpg`. For the most part, I wouldn't recommend using that option with `curl` since it will corrupt any binary files it downloads. There are certainly use cases for it, but this isn't one of them.

Regardless of what was going on with `curl`, it's important to know that **the server code has nothing to do with what the client side does with the headers it receives**. Once the server sends the headers (and the content for that matter), it's completely out of its hands. I can not think of any way the code on the server could force the client to save headers in a file along with the actual content; that's completely up to the client.

**Note:** If you want to see the headers `curl` is receiving (and sending for that matter), try the `-v` option. Received headers will be prefixed with `<` and sent with `>`; lines prefixed with `*` have to do with the connection itself. It looks something like this:

```
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8000
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Sat, 30 Aug 2014 15:54:14 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
[data not shown]
```

Comment: Quick question: what happens to the response headers? Using d.toString() they are saved into the file toghether with the file content.. why this does not apply also when I remove the toString part?

Comment: I updated my answer with some more info on that. Hope it helps :)